# Display row count in server side row model on scroll

Tags: ag-grid, server-side, ag-grid-react

I want to show the displayed row count in server side row model
I tried status bar but that didnt work

I checked the api method in ag hrid getDisplayedRowCount. It tells me total displayed row which is what i expected

But with server side row model i want to get updated row count as user scroll down. How to do that?

Any event api under which i can display updated row count?

Comment: any one please advise?

Comment: Have you tried onBodyScroll event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AG-Grid has modelUpdated event which you can listen to like I explained below in code snippet.

Whenever user reaches the end of the table grid by scrolling, server side provides the data and AG Grid model gets updated thus the property numberofdisplayedrows also change.

```
    gridOptions.onModelUpdated = function(params){ 
    var countOfRows = params.api.getDisplayedRowCount();
    //here do whatever you want to do with this new rowcount.
    }
```

If this helps let me know or else try to put a fiddle or codepen so i can help you.